# SDN4 404 When POSTing commit

Tags: java, spring-test, cucumber-jvm, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am trying to create some tests for my Spring web app. I have some test classes which use MockMvc and a Cucumber test class using Selenium. All tests perform CRUD operations connected to an InProcessServer instance.

When running the tests using Gradle the MockMvc test classes run and pass but when the Cucumber test steps are executed I am getting the following:

```
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 >> "POST /db/data/transaction/commit HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 >> "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 >> "Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 >> "User-Agent: neo4j-ogm.java/1.0[\r][\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 >> "Content-Length: 131[\r][\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 >> "Host: localhost:7478[\r][\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 >> "[\r][\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 >> "{"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH (n:`User`) RETURN COUNT(n)","parameters":{},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false}]}"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found[\r][\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "Date: Thu, 17 Sep 2015 15:44:05 GMT[\r][\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store[\r][\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1[\r][\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "Content-Length: 304[\r][\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "Server: Jetty(9.2.4.v20141103)[\r][\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "[\r][\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "<html>[\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "<head>[\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>[\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "<title>Error 404 </title>[\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "</head>[\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "<body>[\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "<h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2>[\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "<p>Problem accessing /db/data/transaction/commit. Reason:[\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>[\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>[\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "</body>[\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "</html>[\n]"
2015-09-17 16:44:05 INFO  o.s.d.n.config.Neo4jConfiguration - Intercepted exception
```

What could be causing this? This must be the Neo4j server as there is no server running on port 7478 after the tests complete and it is also not the test web server as this is configured on a random port e.g.

```
2015-09-17 16:44:04 INFO  o.s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer - Jetty started on port(s) 37837 (http/1.1)
```

**EDIT:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "co.sens.data.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("co.sens.data")
public class Neo4jTestConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration {
    @Override
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory("co.sens.data");
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
        return new InProcessServer();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public Session getSession() throws Exception {
        return super.getSession();
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of right now is that the TestServer is not starting up properly (or in a timely manner) when the tests are run using Selenium. Can you provide more information about the exception that is being intercepted?

Comment: Why is it posting to /db/data/transaction instead of http://<host>:port?

Comment: @Luanne Because that's correct HTTP. It's the **Host:** part that determines the server address/port

Comment: How is your Neo4jConfiguration set up?

Comment: @Luanne Config class added. This is possibly a ```cucumber-jvm``` issue as JUnit tests work fine.